# p:selectBooleanCheckbox and the label attached to it

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The natural behaviour for a label attached to a checkbox button is to change the state of the button when it (the label) is clicked.
This works in JSF and Richfaces.

Is there a way to make it work in Primefaces(3.5) without involving javascript ?
Is this a bug ?

```
<p:outputLabel for="checkbox" value="Select it:" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" label="My label" value="#{bean.value}" />
```

Comment: It's a bug, see [PF Issue #4678](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4678&q=selectBooleanCheckbox&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work out-of-the-box in plain JSF but in PrimeFaces the `itemLabel` attribute should do it:

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" itemLabel="My label" ... />
```

Comment: This solves the problem of clicking and changing the state, but it doesn't preserve the order of the elements in the screen (label then checkbox). I think `p:outputLabel` should work, this seems to be a real bug.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed since PrimeFaces 4, so you can use `p:outputLabel` with recent versions of PrimeFaces. Good thing of the `p:outputLabel` is that it allows you to add body content to it. So you can add images, icons, a link to  terms and conditions, etc.

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.value}"/>
<p:outputLabel for="@previous">
    Label to <strong>click</strong>
</p:outputLabel>
```